# How to check in pymongo that item is not in list field?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So lets say I have a record like this

```
{   "name" : "Kobe Bryant",
    "jersey_numbers" : [8,24]
}

{   "name" : "Michael Jordan",
    "jersey_numbers" : [23]
}
```

How can i find all the records where in field "jersey_number" number 23 is not included ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $nin operator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

```
players = db['players'].find({ 'jersey_numbers': { "$nin": [ 23 ] } })
```